Linewidth dependence on dipole moment, is it linear or quadratic?
I am trying to calculate the linewidth of a two-level system because of charge noise. I have modeled the charge noise in two ways. I mean, both kinds deal with the correlation of the electric field. One gives me linear dependence on the dipole moment, and the other gives me quadratic dependence. I am kind of confused about how to relate to both of them physically.
For the linear case, I am assuming.
$$|\delta\mathbf{E}|=\sqrt{\left\langle \mathbf{E}^{2}\right\rangle _{t}-\left\langle \mathbf{E}\right\rangle _{t}^{2}}$$ where $\mathbf{E}_{}=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{\mathrm{dip}}}\mathbf{E}_{}^{i}\left(\mathbf{R}_{i}\right)$ is the total electric field, and $\langle\cdots\rangle_{t}$ represents the average over the different configurations (realizations), which correspond to the configuration at different times. We assume $\left\langle \mathbf{E}\right\rangle _{t}=0$ due to the large number of dipoles $N_{\text{dip }}\gg 1$, the random character of the fluctuations considered, i.e., $\left\langle \mathbf{d}_{i}\right\rangle _{t}=0$ and $\left\langle \mathbf{R}_{i}\right\rangle _{t}=0$, and the absence of correlation among the random variables we introduce.
Assuming there is no preferential direction for the total fluctuating electric field $|\delta\mathbf{E}|$, we assume equal fluctuation of the electric field along the $x,y$, and $z$ axes, with a nominal value along any one axis of $|\delta\mathbf{E}|/\sqrt{3}$. For a linewidth produced mainly due to the fluctuations of the $z$ component of the electric field, we obtain
$$\Gamma=\frac{|\delta\mathbf{E}|}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\mathbf{d}\right)\cdot\hat{z}$$
I have calculated linewidth by using the fact that the Gaussian probability function $P(f)$ of emission of a photon with frequency $f$ and mean $\Gamma$  is
$$P\left(f\right)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\Gamma}e^{-\left(f-\bar{f}\left(z\right)\right){}^{2}/2\Gamma^{2}}$$
with frequency emission peaking at
$$\bar{f}\left(z\right)=f+\left(\mathbf{d}\right)\cdot\mathbf{E}\left(z\right)$$
For the quadratic case, we assume we have a two-level system coupled to the electric field and derive the Lindblad master equation, and get the transition rate, which is the real part of the electric field correlation, and then after using $\tau_{\sqrt{1/2}}\Delta E=\pi\hbar/4$ where we have the half lifetime of a resonance state, $\tau_{\sqrt{1/2}}$ and its energy width $\Delta E$ so we used this to relate the lifetime time from the inverse of transition rate we get quadratic dependence.
$$\Gamma=\frac{2\pi\ln2}{\hbar^{2}}\left(d\right)^{2}S\left(-\omega_{a}\right)$$ where $$S\left(\omega\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\langle E_{z}\left(r,t\right)E_{z}\left(r^{\prime},0\right)\right\rangle e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
$d$ is the dipole moment, and for the linear case, I am assuming the maximum
value for the correlation of the fluctuating charge positions.
